# Can't find all the users connected in room in socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mean-stack, meanjs

It's giving me cannot read property of undefined error in server.js file at this line

```
io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[roomName].length;
```

I want to display all the names of users those are connected in the chat room..
I take user name and room name by prompt when first time loads the page...

I am using socket.io v1.5.1

I have tried almost all the codes that are available for >v1.0 but i failed.

Here is my code..

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    var userName = null;
    var roomName = null;

    //creating chat room
    socket.on('createRoom',function(data){
        userName = data.userName;
        //creating or joining room
        socket.join(data.roomName);
        roomName = data.roomName;
        //broadcasting new user joined to all other sockets in room
        socket.broadcast.in(data.roomName).emit('user joined','<span style="color:#10c469 !important;"><strong>'+userName+'</strong> has joined chatroom.</span><br>');

    });

    var userLength = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[roomName].length;
    //Server receives message from client
    socket.on('messageForServer',function(data){
        //will alert all users
        socket.emit('all users',userLength);
     io.sockets.in(data.roomName).emit('messageToBeDisplayed','<strong>'+data.userName+'</strong> : '+data.message+'<br>'); 
    });

    //when user is typing
    socket.on('userIsTyping',function(data){
       socket.broadcast.in(roomName).emit('userIsStillTyping','<span style="color:#ff4242 !important;"<strong>'+userName+'</strong></span> is typing...</br>');
    });

    //when user stops typing
    socket.on('noLongerTyping',function(data){
        socket.broadcast.in(roomName).emit('userIsNotTyping');
    });

    //when user gets bored
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        socket.broadcast.in(roomName).emit('disconnected','<span style="color:#ff4242 !important;"<strong>'+userName+'</strong> has left the chat room.</span><br>');
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChatterBox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/components.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        .bottom{
            position: fixed;     
           text-align: center;    
           bottom: 10px; 
           width: 100%;
        }
        .wrapper{
            padding-top: 4%;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                     ChatterBox 
                </nav>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div id="message-container"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div id="typer-container"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group  bottom">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2">
                            <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message here">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <button type="button" onclick="sendMessage()" class="btn btn-trans btn-inverse waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        //initialize socket library and its object
        var socket = io();

        //taking input from user
        var roomName = prompt("Enter name of chat room that you want to create or join");
        var userName = prompt("Enter your username");

        //create chat room
        socket.emit('createRoom',{roomName:roomName,userName:userName});

        //when user joins the chat room
        socket.on('user joined',function(data){
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += data;
        });

        //to display when user leave chat room
        socket.on('disconnected',function(data){
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += data;
        });

        //Press enter to send message code
        $('#message').keypress(function(event){
            if(event.which == 13){
                sendMessage();
            }
        });

        //Send message to server
        function sendMessage()
        {
            var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
            document.getElementById('message').value = '';
            if(msg){
                socket.emit('messageForServer', {message: msg, roomName:roomName,userName: userName});
            }
        }

        var typing = false;
        var timeout = undefined;

        //when user is no longer typing
        function timeoutFunction(){
          typing = false;
          socket.emit('noLongerTyping');
        }

        function onKeyDownNotEnter(){
          if(typing == false) {

            typing = true;
            socket.emit('userIsTyping',userName+' is typing...');
            timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);

          } else {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);
          }

        }
        //User is typing functionality
        $('#message').keyup(function(event){
            if(event.which != 13 && userName != ''){
                onKeyDownNotEnter();
            }
        });

        socket.on('all users',function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

        //users will see who is typing from this code
        socket.on('userIsStillTyping',function(data){
            document.getElementById('typer-container').innerHTML += data;
        });

        //remove user is typing
        socket.on('userIsNotTyping',function(){
            document.getElementById('typer-container').innerHTML = '';
        });

        //Display broadcasted message
        socket.on('messageToBeDisplayed',function(data){
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += data;
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    //Server receives message from client
    socket.on('messageForServer',function(data){
        //will alert all users
        var userLength = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[roomName].length;
        socket.emit('all users',userLength);
        io.sockets.in(data.roomName).emit('messageToBeDisplayed','<strong>'+data.userName+'</strong> : '+data.message+'<br>'); 
    });
```

But it does not display the names of the connected users but only their number.